# Http Error 500: Internal Server Error - Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

I have a scenario where I need to call a webmethod on pageunload event of javascript.

1. When I open multiple instances of same page in multiple browser tabs(eg greater than 10 tabs).
2. Close the browser at once.

Pageunload for multiple instances of page is called and my error recording tool records the error "Http Error 500: Internal Server Error".

But, nothing is written in log files and I do not get any error message even if the application is in debug mode.

I need to troubleshoot the issue aand prevent it from occurring. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: And your code...? Or are we supposed to guess what are you trying to accomplish and what went wrong? I somewhat doubt you're describing a real-life scenario.

Comment: I need to troubleshoot the issue and prevent it from occurring. And the scenario is of course real life scenario.

Comment: when you say a webmethod do you mean a function in your asp.net code or ..?

Comment: Yes, I have a page method in code behind which needs to be called on page unload event to perform some actions.

Comment: So, you need to troubleshoot an issue, but you're not telling what the issue is, right? By the way, as far as I know, page unload event isn't one of the most reliable out there, are you sure this can't be done any other way whatever you're trying to do?

Comment: The issue is itself in title. And, the main idea behind the page method is to perform some task when the user leave the page and navigates away .

Comment: can you show us the code behind code?. or you can turn on the custom Error mode="off" and debug= true in web.config, so that you can see the error

Comment: When I try to debug the application, the application do not stop on any errors. And it has become difficult to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this method and try to make a logging system to identify the error.

```
 protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnUnload(e);
// your code here


}
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not solve my problem. When I suddenly close the browser window, then this event is not fired. The task which need to be performed when the user navigates away from page or close the browser is not met by using the above lines of code.